# How to convert HTML elements in String in Javascript using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to convert text from text-editor into string. It might be a simple string or a formatted one in form of HTML tags. After converting in string I have to assign string value to Hidden field value. For this I have tried this but HTML tags are not working.

```
 var text = $('#tbNewsEditor').Editor("getText");

 // text is a simple string like "foo" and can be HTML elements like    
 //<p>foo<p/><img src="foo.jpg"/> 

 var str = $(text).prop('outerHTML');
  alert(str);
  $('#hfNewsEditor').val(str);

 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewsEditor" runat="server" />
```

Comment: You want to store the value '<p>foo<p/><img src="foo.jpg"/> ' in the hidden field `hfNewsEditor`?

Comment: @Jenson M John yes I want to store HTML elements in Hidden feild which are being generated by editor

Comment: Try `var str = $('<div>').append(text).html();`

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon tried but I am getting null in hidden feild at server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Change you `asp:HiddenField` to:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNewsEditor" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

or

set hidden field value like this if have js on your aspx page:

```
 $('<%=hfNewsEditor.ClientID%>').val(str);
```

Comment: Tried but no effect I get HTML elements in alert but when I assign them to hidden field getting its value null at server side ?

Comment: when do you call you js function?

Comment: @ Dima Pasko yes this is my js function

Comment: my question was client side event? are you sure that hidden field value is not overridden afterwards? (P.S. look also at the another option in my answers)

Comment: Yes at cleint side I am sure its not overridden. Its working fine in plain text but causing problem when I have HTML elements

Comment: have you succeeded to fix this issue?

Comment: yes but not this way I did encoding and decoding and it worked fine for me